# How to dynamically add a new line to the string stored in the AMP state?

Tags: javascript, html, amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page, google-amp

I'm learning to work with the Accelerated Mobile Pages. I want to add a new line and some text content to a string, stored in the `amp-state`, when the user presses button. So I have tried this:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>

<amp-state id="formState">
  <script type="application/json">
    {
      "message": "Some text"
    }
  </script>
</amp-state>

<textarea [text]="formState.message"></textarea>

<button type="button"
  on="tap:AMP.setState({formState: {message: formState.message + '\nSome another text'} })">
  Button
</button>
```

Unfortunately, it seems that it somehow escapes the `\` character. So I literally got `Some text\nSome another text` in the `textarea`.

I have tried `String.fromCharCode` and so on, but it is prohibited in the AMP... got stuck with this.

I can't find much documentation on this use case, so asking here: is there any way to dynamically add a new line to the string, stored in the `amp-state`, on the user interaction?

Comment: This looks like a bug. I've filed an issue here: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/17863

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the newline:

```
<amp-state id="formState">
  <script type="application/json">
  {
    "message": "Some text",
    "newLine": "\n"
  }
  </script>
</amp-state>
```

then:

```
 on="tap:AMP.setState({formState: {message: formState.message + formState.newLine + 'asdf'} })">
```